# How do I programmatically set a permission to a windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I want to set permission to a service for certain user via C# code on a Windows server as shown below:

[image]

The .NET classes like ServiceController etc. don't have any methods/properties to do this.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please use **words** to describe your problem, rather than inscrutable and unsearchable images.

Comment: Could you add more details to the question? Images are often filtered by security filters and not indexed by the search engines.

Comment: He is trying to set user permissions for a Windows Service, as the title indicates.  It is a good question, asked in a poor way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to use PInvoke from c# to call to the Win32 libraries to be able to set permissions for a Windows service.  It is a bit complicated if you have never done it before, but here is a good example of setting up a Windows service and its associated permissions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540474%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If you know C++, it might be a better idea to use that language, and put the Windows service code in a .dll that you call from C#.  The example above will give you a good start and you should be able to customize what you need to do from there.